# How can I search gpg-encrypted email with notmuch-mutt?

Tags: mutt, gpg, notmuch

I'm using `mutt`, with [`notmuch-mutt`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/notmuch-mutt/) indexing the mail. I have a macro defined in `mutt` to search multiple mailboxes, using `notmuch`'s integration (as suggested in the `man` page).

```
macro index <F3> \
  "<enter-command>set my_old_pipe_decode=\$pipe_decode my_old_wait_key=\$wait_key nopipe_decode nowait_key<enter>\
  <shell-escape>notmuch-mutt -r --prompt search --decrypt<enter>\
  <change-folder-readonly>`echo ${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/notmuch/mutt/results`<enter>\
  <enter-command>set pipe_decode=\$my_old_pipe_decode wait_key=\$my_old_wait_key<enter>" \
  "notmuch: search mail"
```

I also have GPG-encrypted email. `mutt` can unencrypt these fine, and its internal search works perfectly on the encrypted emails. However, `notmuch-mutt` fails to search these properly. Notmuch 0.6 (from 2011) [apparently](http://notmuchmail.org/news/release-0.6/) supports GPG, however this doesn't work for me out of the box. I'm running Notmuch 0.20.2. Is there a way to search encrypted mails using `notmuch-mutt`?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? If so, could you post it?

Comment: No, I still haven't found a solution. FWIW I'm not running Notmuch 0.21 and it's still not working out of the box.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @gf_ (Arch) Linux.

Comment: See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update as of 2018/03/18:** This feature was [merged upstream](https://github.com/notmuch/notmuch/commit/9479baf6f1242e901e090a72a6ac174dc3649a47), and released in notmuch 0.26.

Please note:

> The contents of the index are sufficient to roughly
>   reconstruct the cleartext of the message itself, so please ensure
>   that the notmuch index itself is adequately protected. **DO NOT USE**
>   this feature without considering the security of your index.

See the comments below this answer how to make use of this feature.

--

This is in the works [upstream](https://notmuchmail.org/pipermail/notmuch/2016/021712.html), as of today, 2016/02/09. Quoting the linked mail:

> This is the third draft of the series initially announced in
>   id:1449718786-28000-1-git-send-email-dkg at fifthhorseman.net (second
>   draft was in
>   id:1453258369-7366-1-git-send-email-dkg at fifthhorseman.net).  It
>   differs from v2 in that it incorporates the recent improvements in
>   detecting and processing S/MIME signatures.
>
> From the v2 description:
>
> Notmuch currently doesn't index the cleartext of encrypted mail.  This
>   is the right choice by default, because the index is basically
>   cleartext-equivalent, and we wouldn't want every indexed mailstore to
>   leak the contents of its encrypted mails.
>
> However, if a notmuch user has their index in a protected location,
>   they may prefer the convenience of being able to search the contents
>   of (at least some of) their encrypted mail.
>
> This series of patches enables notmuch to index the cleartext of
>   specific encrypted messages when they're being added via "notmuch new"
>   or "notmuch insert", via a new --try-decrypt flag.
>
> If --try-decrypt is used, and decryption is successful for part of a
>   message, the message gets an additional "index-decrypted" tag.  If
>   decryption of part of a message fails, the message gets an additional
>   "index-decryption-failed" tag.
>
> v2 addresses the concerns raised from the helpful feedback on the
>   previous series, and adds a notmuch_indexopts_t object that can be
>   used to declare options for indexing messages, including a
>   "try_decrypt" boolean.
>
> Additionally, this series adds a new function to libnotmuch:
>
> notmuch_message_reindex (notmuch_message_t *message,
>                              notmuch_indexopts_t *indexopts)
>
> Which allows user of the library to adjust the indexing options of a
>   given message.
>
> The CLI is additionally augmented with a new notmuch subcommand,
>   "notmuch reindex", which also has a --try-decrypt flag.
>
> So a user who has their message index stored securely and wants to
>   index the cleartext of all encrypted messages they've received can do
>   something like:
>
> notmuch reindex --try-decrypt tag:encrypted and not tag:index-decrypted
>
> Or can clear all indexed cleartext from their database with:
>
> notmuch reindex tag:encrypted and tag:index-decrypted

Comment: Just as an update, it looks like this feature has still not been implemented. There have been a dozen updates to `notmuch`, but `reindex` hasn't been added yet. The "bug tracker" is very hard to search, but I think [this](https://notmuchmail.org/pipermail/notmuch/2016/022849.html) is the most recent post.

Comment: It was finally merged and released in notmuch 0.26. :)

Comment: @gf I tried `$ notmuch config set index.try_decrypt true`, which added `try_decrypt=true` to `~/.notmuch-config`, then I tried `$ notmuch reindex --try-decrypt tag:encrypted and not tag:index-decrypted`, but got `Unrecognized option: --try-decrypt`. I'm using notmuch 0.26.

Comment: @Sparhawk Where did you get `--try-decrypt` from?

Comment: @Sparhawk In case you've referred to the above patch: This was a first iteration, the options changed since then, AFAIK. See [this commit](https://github.com/notmuch/notmuch/commit/d3964e81ac98825a025a6120c488ebd73de2a281).

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for that! FWIW the full command is `notmuch reindex --decrypt=true tag:encrypted and not tag:index-decrypted`. (And `notmuch config set index.decrypt true`.)

Comment: @Sparhawk Great... so, works for you? :)

Comment: Yes it works perfectly! I tested indexing existing encrypted emails with the first command, and they are now searchable. I then tested indexing new emails after the second command plus `notmuch new`, and they also indexed perfectly.

Comment: Great! :) I've added some more information, for other people reading this, in the beginning of the answer.